# Deserialize object with List<byte> member from XML

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

Have come across XML deserialization issue of class instances with `List<byte>` public properties when that properties have default definition in class constrictor

Say we have class:

```
public class TestClass
{
    public List<byte> ByteList;
    public TestClass()
    {
        this.ByteList = new List<byte>() { 0x01, 0x02 };
    }
}
```

then we have following code to test serialization/deserialization

```
TestClass testClass = new TestClass();
Console.WriteLine("testClass.ByteList.Count: {0}", testClass.ByteList.Count);

System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(TestClass));
using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(@".\testClass.xml", System.IO.FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, testClass);
}
Console.WriteLine("testClass.ByteList.Count: {0}", testClass.ByteList.Count);

TestClass deserializedTestClass = null;
using (System.IO.FileStream sr = new System.IO.FileStream(@".\testClass.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Open))
{
    deserializedTestClass = (TestClass)xmlSerializer.Deserialize(sr);
}
Console.WriteLine("deserializedTestClass.ByteList.Count: {0}", deserializedTestClass.ByteList.Count);
```

as a result we see on console following output:

> testClass.ByteList.Count: 2
>
> testClass.ByteList.Count: 2
>
> deserializedTestClass.ByteList.Count: 4

serialization result xml is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<TestClass xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ByteList>
    <unsignedByte>1</unsignedByte>
    <unsignedByte>2</unsignedByte>
  </ByteList>
</TestClass>
```

Could somebody explain what is going on here and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameterless constructor for TestClass initializes ByteList to a non-empty list (i.e. with the values { 1, 2 }). Then the deserialization adds the two elements found in the XML to that non-empty list. So of course the list winds up with all 4 elements.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, expected behavior of XmlSerializer when deserializing into generics List is not assigning newly deserialized value but executing AddRange on collection?

Comment: I would say the docs are vague on the point. But it's pretty clear what's actually happening, so in that sense, yes. If you already have initialized the object for the field, the serializer reuses that object instead of creating a new one for you.